# Box with two lines appears on System.Windows.Window

Tags: windows, visual-studio-extensions

[image: Box with two lines]

Hi i ran into something annoying while creating a Windows Window.
Im using the System.Window.Window base class with a single BlockText & Border element to create a tooltip like window.
The issue is that at a certain width a black box width 2 lines appears (@see screenshot).
Any way to get rid of it? Im not sure if this is connected to windows itself. Or if this is a extern thing.

Thanks a lot

I played around with the settings but couldn´t find any way to remove this. (Changing layout elements, switching screens, change window bar settings etc etc)

Comment: That's the XAML Hot Reload toolbar. if you don't like it, uncheck "Enable XAML Hot Reload" in Tools.Options.Debugging.

Comment: Hi, Does Raymond's solution work for you? I tested it in VS 2022 and worked well.

Comment: @ Raymond Chen  You could post the content in comment as an answer that makes easy for original post to accept your answer.